# pymysql: hide credential of my file

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql

I have the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://edamame:mypassword@1.2.3.4:3306/mydb')
```

I want to hide the part: `edamame:mypassword@1.2.3.4:3306/mydb` . Probably put into another file which is not committed to the repo.

I could just read in strings from another file, but I am wondering what is the better practice or design to achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that's the right idea. I like yaml for basic config files, but you could use whatever format you'd like. If you use yaml, it would go something like this:

1. Make a yaml file outside your repo with appropriate read/write/execute permissions.

   ```
   database_info:
       username: edamame
       password: mypassword
       host: 1.2.3.4
       port: 3306
       database: mydb
   ```
2. Import with PyYAML.

   ```
   import yaml
   with open('your/file/path/here/db_config.yaml', 'r') as infile:
       db_cfg = yaml.safe_load(infile)
   ```
3. Access the variables and populate your string (I usually wrap this in a function):

   ```
   engine = create_engine(
       'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(
           db_cfg['database_info']['username'],
           db_cfg['database_info']['mypassword'],
           db_cfg['database_info']['host'],
           db_cfg['database_info']['port'],
           db_cfg['database_info']['database']
       )
   )
   ```

Make sure your config file is not in the repo and that the directory/file permissions are correct. If you're building a web application, another good option are environment variables. You can access those using Python's os library.

Comment: ``yaml.load()`` for PyYAML is documented to be unsafe. With that YAML there is no reason not to use `yaml.safe_load()`. Is there a specific reason to use the outdated PyYAML, a  library that still not supports the YAML 1.2 standard (a standard released over 9 years ago)?

Comment: You should not put things like "edit 2:" in your posts that information is irrelevant for new viewers of your answer. There always is edit history and comments (that can be removed when no longer relevant).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Anthon. You're right that safe_load() is the better choice (updated). PyYAML is still maintained and YAML 1.1 is sufficient for this use case - is there a limitation of 1.1 that you have in mind?